# Software to emulate a slow network connection

Tags: networking, emulator, performance-analysis, proxy

Our developers typically run and test code for a 3 tier architecture on their machines prior to sending this over to be tested.
If there are lots of cross-tier calls, those often aren't picked up until later test stages.

In order to help them realise these issues sooner, I'm wondering if there's a tool which would allow us to hijack communication on certain ports and add a delay; e.g. if working with a SQL database we'd ensure only TCP pipes were enabled, then slow port 1433 to simulate a LAN connection instead of local machine.

I think MS Newt (network emulator windows toolkit) may do this, but I can't find a download/recent version; only info on [a version included in VS2010 Bits](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/juanand/2010/03/05/standalone-network-emulator-tool/).

I'm also not sure whether this works when all components are on the same machine, or if it only works to limit external network connections, as haven't found too much explaining the tool.

The software I seek should …

- run on Windows 7 and/or Windows Server 2008 R2
- be permitted for commercial use
- preferably be free (I'd be flexible on price depending on what we get)

Though I'm interested in seeing what's out there for the functional requirement, then whittling down the options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Clumsy`](https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/index.html) is available on Github, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22845355/5971390)

[`dummynet`](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/) is available on [Github](https://github.com/luigirizzo/dummynet), which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3422372/5971390)

`NEWT` was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12236635/5971390) and a download link is available [here](https://blog.mrpol.nl/2010/01/14/network-emulator-toolkit/) which has links for [64 bit](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=259DBF32D413DA06!164&authkey=!ANTxWext38ripAM) and [32 bit](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=259DBF32D413DA06!163&authkey=!AO8XD34WFOJGcLw)